# VS11 и Python Tools (py 3.3), проблема с кодировкой при команде input()

Tags: python, visual-studio

Позавчера после установки VS11,  а также PyTools столкнулся с такой проблемой как неправильное отображение комментария к 'input()', а точнее вместо текста какие-то крокозябры.
С английским языком все нормально, а вот с русским, проблема.
Проблема в том что через 'print' русский шрифт выводится нормально.
Через консоль и через idle все отображается отлично.

---

Как обойти проблему в принципе я нашел, но все равно интересно в чем причина.

изображение по ссылке:
 1. http://clip2net.com/s/2L3sa
 2. http://clip2net.com/s/2L3un

Comment: проблема в кодировках. текст у Вас в utf-8, консоль в 866, а редактор может быть как в utf-8, так и в cp1251. Английские буквы имеют одинаковые кодировки, а вот кириллица - нет.

Comment: а как все таки решить проблему эту?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос оказался довольно таки интересным. :) На самом деле, у автора задана кодировка utf-8 для интерпретатора и уже то, что `print` корректно выводит юникод, значит, что исходник также сохранен в utf-8 и проблем быть не должно.

Я быстренько набросал похожий тест и выяснилось, что описанная автором проблема действительно стабильно вопроизводится при запуске интерпретатора в режиме отладки из VS. То есть, `print` выводит корректно, `input` - нет. При запуске интерпретатором питона напрямую (`python3 test.py`), во всех случаях имеем корректный вывод. *Причина не в исходных кодах.*

Оказалось, что на CodePlex есть имеющий к этому прямое отношение [баг](https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/144). Похоже, что вывод скрипта во время отладки из VS редиректится в некий промежуточный класс для дублирования вывода в Debug Output, который по пути "теряет" юникодовые символы. В качестве временного решения могу посоветовать отключить этот функционал, сняв вот эту галку:

[image: Параметры]

В моем случае это помогло корректно вывести символы. Недостаток - в табе Output/Вывод больше не дублируется вывод скрипта в консоль.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, ваше решение мне очень помогло!